# if you didn't understand vs if you hadn't understood

Tags: past-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

I'm trying to make a sentence. However, I'm a little bit confused about the right tense here.

> How you can find a solution if you hadn't understood the problem.

It should be written in the `past perfect` because you have to understand the problem first then you can find a solution for that.

> How you can find a solution if you didn't understand the problem.

Or should be written in the `simple past` form, just because!

> how you can find a solution if you don't understand the problem.

Or even `simple present` because it is a fact.

Please let me know if there is a better way to rewrite this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are conditions:

> If you do not understand the problem...
>
> If you did not understand the problem...
>
> If you had not understood the problem...

each referring to a particular time.

The present tense can be used to refer to general truths (or questions that resolve to a general truth):

> Fish live in water.
>
> If you *do not understand* a problem, you cannot solve it.
>
> If you do not understand a problem, how can you solve it?

The past perfect would be used in conjunction with another past tense, because you're emphasizing a sequence of events in the past:

> How **did** you **solve** the problem (on the exam yesterday) when you **had not understood** it  (during our study group's pre-exam review)?

You could also ask:

> How have you managed to solve the problem when you did not understand it?

using the present perfect and the simple past.

The problem-solving there is understood to be current or very recent, and the lack of understanding predated the solving.

Comment: Thank you so much man for your comprehensive response. Now I understand.